# Is it possible to avoid recursion and StackOverflowError in OneToMany-ManyToOne bi-directional relations?

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, recursion, one-to-many, many-to-one

[image]

I use **Spring Boot** and Thymeleaf to create a web application.

When I debug my application, it works very SLOW. Every F8-step a debugger shows message **"Collecting data..."** on my objects. And I can't see the state of my objects for a long time (10-60 seconds).

[image]

Finally, when collecting data is done, I see **StackOverflowError**.

[image]

I understand that in this situation there is an infinite recursion. Car links to Service, Service links to Car, and so on. And it overflows `toString()` method for each object.

I see many examples of using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations. All them cause this recursion and StackOverflowError. And in this case engineers recommend to put `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonManagedReference`/`@JsonBackReference` annotations to fix infinite recursion.

Those advises works fine for REST API serialized object.

The problem is that **I'm not developing REST API**. I make **Web MVC application**.

So what can you recommend me to fix this recursion and have a fast-debug application?

Is it a bad design? Or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working solution for the problem:

1. First need to mark `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation to have better performance while debugging.
2. Second thing that has to be done is to modify standard IDE-generated `toString` method. For nested objects you should return not the whole object, but just an object ID.

Example for `Service`:

Before modification:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Service{" +
        "serviceId=" + serviceId +
        ", car=" + car +
        ", event='" + event + '\'' +
        ", created=" + created +
        ", modified=" + modified +
        '}';
  }
```

After modification:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
    String carId;
    if (car == null) {
      carId = "null";
    } else {
      carId = car.getCarId().toString();
    }
    return "Service{" +
        "serviceId=" + serviceId +
        ", carId=" + carId +
        ", event='" + event + '\'' +
        ", created=" + created +
        ", modified=" + modified +
        '}';
  }
```

Now I don't get debugger `"Collecting data..."` message and `StackOverflowError` exception.

Debug performance is good!

Answer (score 1):

I am not experiencing such issues during debugging, I think this is more related to your design.
However try adding LAZY, e.g.:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

this could help.

Comment: Your answer is useful. It partly helped to solve performance issue during debugging. Thanks